# How to access a remote resource from an android code

Tags: android

Firstly , i must admit that i'm pretty new to the whole android coding so it could probably seem to anyone that this is a fairly obvious question. I undertook a project , on my own volition , which i will probably finish in a couple of years of making it slowly when i have time , mainly to learn the basics of android coding. So , here goes nothing:

I'm currently creating a kind of "server" which mainly works as a reference point. What it will do is hold the information of WHERE some resource is stored instead of storing it itself. So my question is:

The basic idea for `<item>` in android is , as stated from the developer site is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:id="@[+][package:]id/resource_name"
          android:title="string"
          android:titleCondensed="string"
          android:icon="@[package:]drawable/drawable_resource_name"
          android:onClick="method name"
          android:showAsAction=["ifRoom" | "never" | "withText" | "always" | "collapseActionView"]
          android:actionLayout="@[package:]layout/layout_resource_name"
          android:actionViewClass="class name"
          android:actionProviderClass="class name"
          android:alphabeticShortcut="string"
          android:numericShortcut="string"
          android:checkable=["true" | "false"]
          android:visible=["true" | "false"]
          android:enabled=["true" | "false"]
          android:menuCategory=["container" | "system" | "secondary" | "alternative"]
          android:orderInCategory="integer" />
    <group android:id="@[+][package:]id/resource name"
           android:checkableBehavior=["none" | "all" | "single"]
           android:visible=["true" | "false"]
           android:enabled=["true" | "false"]
           android:menuCategory=["container" | "system" | "secondary" | "alternative"]
           android:orderInCategory="integer" >
        <item />
    </group>
    <item >
        <menu>
          <item />
        </menu>
    </item>
</menu>
```

My question is how to modify this in order to point to a remote resource , as this is what i want to accomplish , instead of a local one. For clarification , the remote resource is in another android system and not desktop. If i was looking for desktop remote connections , the endless googling would have helped me but i didn't find anything so , that's it i guess

What i want to accomplish is this:
A device requests something from the server who in turn sends the aforementioned device to what it requested. I imagined that could be done by managing the resource attributes which is the reason i'm posting that part here. Sorry for any mix up my unedited post might have created and thanks eveyrone in case for taking the time to read it

Comment: Not 100% sure what is being asked, but the xml files themselves don't usually point at remote resources. Most of them are packaged and resolved at the compilation phase of the app. So in the case of the menu file, the `aapt` tool will evaluate the xml file and create symbols in the code so that a particular file and any identifiable entities within it. can be referenced. i.e. `R.menu.my_menu` Any remote resource or remote access is usually done within code and custom to the application (although there are a variety of standard tools to choose from depending on your needs

Answer (score 1):

> The basic idea for  in android is , as stated from the developer site is:

You are referencing the documented structure for a `menu` resource. Nowadays, this is used typically to configure an action bar or action mode.

> My question is how to modify this in order to point to a remote resource

You don't. Resources are compiled into your Android application. They are not modifiable at runtime, and you cannot download data from the Internet and treat that data identically to the way that you treat resources.

You are certainly welcome to download an XML file that defines a menu, parse that XML, and use Java classes (`Menu` and `MenuItem`, mostly) to create the corresponding objects to be used by the action bar or action mode. Few developers do this, which means if you are trying "to learn the basics of android coding", this would be an unusual path to go down.

Comment: I'm using this project as a "grand scheme" to learn the ins and outs , it doesn't only have easy level coding , it encompasses pretty much everything so in effect when i'm done with it (years down the line) i would be able to say i know in some extent to work android code. Do you suggest i leave this for later? When i'm more...experienced with this?

Comment: @stonedevil: "Do you suggest i leave this for later? When i'm more...experienced with this?" -- I do not know you or your project. The only suggestion that I can make is for you to ask somewhere (here or another site) whether this approach (defining action bar contents based on downloaded data instead of resources) is the best solution for whatever problem it is that you are trying to solve. Perhaps there is something else that is more typical in Android apps and their development that you should use. Or, perhaps indeed this path is the right answer. I have no way to know.